# How to install stanford NLP to use it in C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, stanford-nlp

I want to use stanford NLP library in one of my C++ project. But I do not understand how to install it, the guidance given in the page is confusing, please can anyone give me some guidance, I really need it. It would be best if you can show me some image or video guide on how to use it.

PS. I am running in Window 11 and using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 as my compiler.

PSS. Link to the library : https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Comment: 1. Can you add a link to this library? 2. Things are never just "confusing" in general. There's always a specific word or concept you don't understand. What exactly is confusing about those instructions?

Comment: 1. I had added the link to library, 2. The instruction given was for Java / python and I am working for C++ (or maybe I am too dumb to understand how to work around with it).

Comment: Oh. I see. Then I would google for C++ libraries to interoperate with Java or Python, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

CoreNLP (Natural Language Processing) is a Java library.
To access Java from C++, use JNI (Java Native Interface): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-native-interface
C headers for Java libraries can be generated using javah: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/18/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html